# "Quanto ha?" per chiedere l'età (di un neonato)

Tags: word-usage

In un libro di lingua italiana per stranieri, ho letto il dialogo seguente (enfasi mia):

> - Che bel bambino!
> - Ha gli occhi azzurri come sua nonna e i capelli ricci come suo padre.
> - **Quanto ha?**
> - Sei mesi.
> - [... ecc.]

"Quanto ha?" sembra sbagliato in questo contesto. Per lo meno io non l'ho mai sentito, né usato così. Io direi piuttosto "Quanti anni (o mesi) ha?" Invece, se qualcuno mi chiedesse "Quanto ha?", penserei che si riferisse a "Quanto ha di febbre? (O magari di scarpe...)", per esempio.

Potete confermare (o smentire) che sia sbagliata la domanda "Quanto ha?" in questo contesto?

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie Charo :)

Answer (score 5):

Non ha molto senso chiedersi se sia “giusto” o “sbagliato”: se si usa, fa parte della lingua. A me suona perfettamente normale: magari il suo uso è maggiore o minore a seconda delle zone d'Italia. (Io sono di Roma.)

Probabilmente si usa dire così perché le alternative porrebbero qualche problema: in genere si chiede di bambini piccoli, e quindi non avrebbe senso chiedere quanti anni hanno; ma oltre i primi mesi, non viene spontaneo ragionare in mesi (per esempio, si dice “ha un anno e mezzo”, non “ha diciotto mesi”). Quindi, visto che nella vita vera non si può chiedere “Quanti anni (o mesi) ha?”, questa è più o meno l'unica possibilità.

(Tanto per chiarire: non vedo come possa essere “sbagliato”. “Quanto” è un pronome interrogativo, “ha” è un verbo alla terza persona singolare, in quanto si riferisce a qualcuno che non è né chi parla né chi ascolta. Al massimo è un po' vago, ma il contesto (e l'intuito dei neogenitori) chiarisce il senso. È come se io chiedessi a qualcuno “Quanto hai fatto?” A seconda del contesto sarà chiaro se parliamo di soldi, di un risultato sportivo, di una velocità, o che altro.)

Comment: D'accordo, può darsi che sia sbagliato chiedere se questa domanda "è sbagliata" :) Allora farei la domanda così: "È una domanda che la maggioranza degli italiani farebbe o per lo meno capirebbe?" E da quanto hai scritto, ho capito che la risposta è sì.

Answer (score 4):

Espando un po' la risposta di DaG, che come giustamente osserva, il fatto che tale modo di dire possa sembrare strano probabilmente deriva da consuetudini locali.

In questo contesto, dalle mie parti (zona Bologna/Pistoia), `"Quanto ha?"`, si dice, anche se forse sembra un po' vago, ed il fatto che ci si riferisca all'età lo si capisce dal contesto: in genere se guardo un bambino molto piccolo e chiedo `"Quanto ha?"`, è abbastanza naturale che mi stia riferendo all'età.

Si può anche dire `"Quanto tempo ha?"`, sempre in un contesto di bambini molto piccoli, dove `"tempo"` è implicitamente utilizzato al posto di `"mesi"`, mentre se si tratta di bambini un po' più grandicelli, l'unica espressione che mi sia capitato di sentire è la comune `"Quanti anni ha?"`.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Grazie mille :)

Answer (score 0):

Non penso si tratti di un'espressione particolarmente corretta, anche se ormai è entrata nel vocabolario quotidiano come sinonimo di `quanti anni / che età ha?` Ho sentito usare quest'espressione diverse volte in un contesto colloquiale, quasi sempre riferendosi all'età di un bambino o di un animale.

Comment: In che senso non è “corretto”?

Comment: Mi verrebbe da dire che è "incorretto" nello stesso modo in cui l'utilizzo improprio di "piuttosto che" (http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2017/01/19/uso-improprio-di-piuttosto-che/) è entrato nell'uso comune.

Comment: Non colgo il nesso, scusami. Che c'entra “piuttosto che” con “quanto ha?”? (Oltre al fatto che tu li consideri entrambi scorretti.)

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!